# How to slide a text after a fixed time interval

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I want to animate a text from top to bottom on a slider. Here is the css which I am using to animate it:

Html:

```
 <p class="rg5 slideInDown" id="text-animation">mobile</p>
```

css:

```
.rg5 {
  font-family: roboto sans-serif;;
  font-size: 52px;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-bottom: 10%;
  line-height: 1;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  animation: slidein 5s infinite;
  -webkit-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation: slidein 5s infinite;
  -moz-animation: slidein 5s infinite; 
  -o-animation: slidein 5s infinite;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.slidein {
  -moz-animation-duration: 5s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  -moz-animation-name: slidein;
  -webkit-animation-name: slidein;
  animation-name: slidein;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 3;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 3;
  animation-iteration-count: 3;
  -moz-animation-direction: alternate;
  -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}
@-moz-keyframes slidein {
  from { 
   -moz-transform: translate(1,-30em) scale(1.2);
}
  to { 
    -moz-transform: translate(1em,1) scale(1.2);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes slidein {
  from { -webkit-transform: translate(0s,-20em) scale(1.2);
  }
  to { -webkit-transform: translate(0em,0) scale(1.2);
  }  
}
@keyframes slidein {
  from { 
    transform: translate(0,-20em) scale(1.2);
  }
  to { 
    transform: translate(0em,0) scale(1.2);
  }
}
```

Its working perfectly while sliding top to bottom but there should be 15sec time gap between animations.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using pure css and usage of `setInterval` is not advised.

You can use `animation-iteration-count: infinite;` & `animation-delay: 15s;` for the time gap between subsequent animations.

Refer code:

```css
.rg5 {
  font-family: roboto sans-serif;
  font-size: 52px;
  color: black;
  margin-bottom: 10%;
  line-height: 1;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  animation: slidein 5s infinite;
  -webkit-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 1s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation: slidein 5s infinite;
  -moz-animation: slidein 5s infinite;
  -o-animation: slidein 5s infinite;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.slidein {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 15s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  -moz-animation-delay: 15s;
  animation-delay: 15s;
}

@-moz-keyframes slidein {
  from {
    -moz-transform: translate(1, -30em) scale(1.2);
  }
  to {
    -moz-transform: translate(1em, 1) scale(1.2);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slidein {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0s, -20em) scale(1.2);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0em, 0) scale(1.2);
  }
}

@keyframes slidein {
  from {
    transform: translate(0, -20em) scale(1.2);
  }
  to {
    transform: translate(0em, 0) scale(1.2);
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="rg5 slideInDown" id="text-animation">mobile</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use setInterval function to keep 15 sec time gap.

```
setInterval(function()
{ 
     your_function(); 
}, 15000);
```

Comment: mahesh i am not using jquery for animation i am using css so please tell me how to implement with css.If its possible with jquery then let me know the complete function.